# How to exclude files from the packaging in serverless.yaml?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I have the following configuration in my `serverless.yaml` file:

```
provider:
  package:
    exclude:
      - ./**
    include:
      - src/**
```

But anyways all the folders in my root are being included in the service `.zip` file.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the package outside provider

```
  provider:


  package:
    exclude:
      - ./**
    include:
      - src/**
```

And if you have multiple lambdas in same file then you can add the package as such

```
  functions:
     Function1:
        handler: functions_folder/.Function1.handler
        package:
           include:
              - functions_folder/Function1.js
```